# Change incoming downloads folder in OpenELEC

Tags: openelec

I am running Transmission v0.7.6 on OpenELEC v4.1.2 on my Raspberry Pi Model B. All downloads are first saved to my SD card and when complete are moved to my external hard drive.

How do I change the incomplete downloads folder from my SD card to my external hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

The settings.json file is located at /storage/.cache/transmission/settings.json. Further details can be found at https://gist.github.com/yyolk/4747010.

Answer (score 1):

If you use transmission with GUI, go to `Edit>Preferences>Downloads`. There you can adjust anything you want. If you don't, here's it: https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles#FilesandLocations